# How can I find exact value for this function?

Tags: r

I would like to find exact values for this Laplace density, for example, what is the value of function for x1=0.462234 and x2=0.53885.

```
x <- seq(from=0, to = 1, by= 0.001)
laplace <- (1/(2*0.08))*exp(-abs(x-0.5)/(0.08))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
laplace <- function(x) {
    1 / (2 * 0.08) * exp(-abs(x - 0.5) / 0.08);
}

x <- c(0.462234, 0.53885);
laplace(x);
#[1] 3.898167 3.845703
```